# Entity Framework receives Access Denied, while plain SQL commands not

Tags: entity-framework-6.1

I am trying to force Entity Framework to create database at my desired location, but it always complains on "Access denied":

> Error was:   Unhandled exception: (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException)
>   Unable to open the physical file "D:\te_mp\zeliboba_odin.mdf".
>   Operating system error 5: "5(Access denied.)".

But if I use plain SQL Commands with the same connection string - then DB is created successfully.

```
var createDbSql = String.Format(
                "CREATE DATABASE {0} ON PRIMARY (NAME = {0}_Data, FILENAME = '{1}.mdf', SIZE = 10MB, " +
                " FILEGROWTH = 10%)  LOG ON (NAME = {0}_Log,  FILENAME = '{1}.ldf',  SIZE = 1MB, FILEGROWTH = 10%) ",
                dbName, filename);
```

What's the difference between these two cases? Why EF fails?

Update 1:
First connection string is: 
    var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
This will work got plain SQL commands sent to server - I am creating databases right now.
Next I create DB, and I have its name. So I do like this:
    var connectionString = String.Format(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;database={0}", dbName);
    sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    using (var db = new MyDbContext(sqlConnection, true)) {
      // EF creates database without any troubles.
    }

What I tried with EF - set AttachDatabaseFile (cant remember exact name of parameter). EF really tries to create a database at provided location, but it fails with Access denied error. I tried to play with args in connection string, but I failed, and I do not know how can I point EF to create database at particular folder with particular filenames (making sure SQL Server can create database there itself).

Comment: How are you setting the connection string in both cases? Which is teh conenction string? You're making something wrong!!

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server database engine service account must have permissions to read/write in the new folder.

[Attaching Database – Unable to Open Physical File (Access is Denied)](http://dbamohsin.wordpress.com/2009/06/03/attaching-database-unable-to-open-physical-file-access-is-denied/)

Comment: And it has. If I use plain SQL commands - SQL server create database there. But Entity Framework can't!